# Preserve value of iDisplayStart in jquery datatable

Tags: datatables

Whenever I try to filter column,the value of iDisplayStart becomes 0.How I can prevent this.I am doing server side coding in asp.net mvc

Comment: Can we see some code please? The controller method would help.

Comment: this is my code for loading data page no. wise:filteredEmployees = emp
                   .Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(nameFilter.ToLower())
                   &&
                   c.Age.ToString().Contains(ageFilter)
                   &&
                   c.Address.ToLower().Contains(addressFilter.ToLower())
                   ).Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength); But when I type something in filtering textbox the value of iDisplayStart becomes 0.But i want it still 10 when i am in page 2 or 20 when i am in page 3 etc.

Comment: So param.iDisplayStart is always 0? how are you passing it to the controller?